# spreadsheet in odoo 16 is not saved

Tags: odoo, spreadsheet, odoo-16

I have some issues in the spreadsheet document in Odoo 16. So, when I add input in the first cell and then add input again to another cell, when I close the spreadsheet, it is not saved. The saving indicator takes a long time to load.
[image]